# Is there a hotkey sequence to send minerals or gas to your ally?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a hotkey sequence to send minerals or gas to your ally? Alternatively is there a way to bind hotkeys to the action?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to summon the Team Resources menu. Should you want to send many resources at once, use the scrollwheel to increase the resource count (it's far faster than clicking the GUI button). Holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while clicking the increase or decrease buttons [apparently](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/713493#c-650437892) uses increments of 100.

I don't believe there is any in-game way to bind a pre-determined amount to a key.

Comment: Mouse wheel scroll is excellent - with a fast-scrolling mouse, you can send towards 10k minerals in under a second.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind the resource trading menu. Found under Hotkeys > Global > Menu but like [sequentiallee](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1162/sequentiallee) mentioned, I don't believe there is any in-game way to bind a pre-determined amount to a key.