# How do I give resources to my teammates, quickly, in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Usually, due to my wretched management (or sometimes due to a mass OC strategy), I have a lot of unused minerals.

I understand that one of my primary goals is "to keep money low", but sometimes during team games it would be better if I passed 1-2 thousand resources to my teammates, who seem to be better than me.

When I open the "Money transfer" window, I can increase the amount of resources to transfer by 50 by clicking on the arrows. This is **very** slow: I could waste 10 seconds clicking those numbers.

Is there any way to quickly increase the number of resources to transfer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/starcraft-2-hotkeys-for-resource-sharing-with-allies/7916#7916

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate, but the key to speed is to use the mouse scroll-wheel over the mineral/gas values.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but I always tell my teammates to request funds if they need them.  Someone without money has more free apm than someone with money.

Comment: @Lee I don't think this is a duplicate. The other one asks for a shortcut to the trade window, this one asks for a faster way to do something once that window is already open. Related, yes, but not duplicate. It's true your answer there also covers this question, but that's extra information you added there which wasn't really required by the question.

Comment: @Oak The other question makes no mention of the resource trading window. I believe it sought a way to hotkey the entire process. Given that a hotkey's purpose is only to speed up actions I think this is the same question worded differently.

Comment: @Lee oh, I see what you mean. Yes, I guess this could be a duplicate, though the title of the other question could be changed to not specifically mention hotkeys.

Comment: @sblair: I'm wondering if the CTRL key has effect on the scroll-wheel...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Holding CTRL allows you to do this in steps of 100 instead of 50.