# Faster ways to transfer resources & share control with other players?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StarCraft 2 Hotkeys for Resource Sharing with Allies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/starcraft-2-hotkeys-for-resource-sharing-with-allies)

Are there faster ways than using the mouse in Starcraft 2 to:

1. Transfer minerals/gas to another player; and
2. Share control with another player?

It's quite time-consuming to have to click on the small button in the top-right, select a player, click the tiny up/down arrows, etc. to transfer minerals/gas.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for those menus?  Or does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this faster?

Comment: Closing as duplicate since as far as I can tell, that other question covers both the keyboard shortcut to bring up the menu and a faster way increase the amount of resources shared.

Comment: Maybe you should wait to let the community close a question rather than moderating it - if you hadn't jumped in so quickly you might have noticed that the "exact duplicate" is only a partial duplicate - it doesn't cover sharing control with your allies at all.

Comment: @Joe the mechanics are identical.  In an ideal world, the older question would be closed as a duplicate of this one, and its answers merged here.  Unfortunately, merging of questions is still a little clunky.

Comment: @tzenes: No they're not. The hotkey for the share resources menu is ctrl+F12. There is no hotkey for the alliances menu.

Comment: @Joe I meant the mechanics of closing as duplicate...