# Is it possible to see the other players races once I am in the game in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I often play 2v2 or 3v3 games. Usually it takes quite long until everybody is ready and I can checkout their races. But sometimes I forget to look or the game loads very fast and I do not know what my opponents are.

Sometimes my ally knows or the opponents are decent enough to tell me their races.

Is it somehow possible to checkout the opponents race inside a game? I mean the information is no secret as the load screens reveals them and it is not possible to switch during the game.

This is not directly related, but is it possible to query the opponents favorite (most played) race during a game.

Comment: Why don't you seperate the second question: "is it possible to query the opponents favorite (most played) race during a game." into it's own question? I'll have an answer for you if you do.

Comment: @chobok: I created a new question here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63083/is-it-possible-to-query-the-opponents-favorite-most-played-race-and-other-stat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you are in game you can click the icon in the top right hand corner labelled "Toggle Alliance menu" to see what race everyone is, including the opponents. If they had chosen random at the start of the game they will show up in game as random. For those opponents you will have to scout to find out what they are.

In the case of seeing an opponents most played race while in game, this is not possible.

Comment: It will also show "random" if that's what the player went for. If you're wondering what his random ended up as, your only option is to scout his base, or ask him.

Comment: Is there a hotkey for "Toggle Alliance"? I suspect not, but just wondering. (Never mind, found the answer here:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/is-there-a-hotkey-sequence-to-send-minerals-or-gas-to-your-ally)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the alliances tab to see other players' races when you are in the match.