# Is it possible to query the opponents favorite (most played) race and other stats during a game?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Warcraft 3 it is possible to query some stats of your opponent during a game to see how good he is. The command is "/stats playername". Is something similar possible in Starcraft 2?

I want to see his league and his main race.

Comment: I could try to use some site like sc2ranks.com, but even if I am fast enough to Alt-Tab and enter his nickname, I don't know his characer code.

Comment: I was able to search and find players on sc2ranks.com even without character codes. SC2Ranks.com appears to be down at the moment. I'll post an answer when I can access SC2Ranks, so that I go write the precise steps it would take to search for a player without their character code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in dbemerlin's answer, it is not possible through the game client. You can obtain a lot information from www.sc2ranks.com:

1. when you have spare time during the game, or during the loading screen, alt-tab to a browser and go to: www.sc2ranks.com
2. click on the "Search" tab (it is on the second row)
3. enter in your search details and search!

If there are multiple characters with the same name, you'll see a list of all of them. As ayckoster mentions in his comment, you can't be sure which one you are playing against, but you maybe be able to infer from their character information which one you are playing against.

You can infer be **looking at the type of game you are playing** (1v1, 2v2, 3v3, 4v4, FFA), and seeing which of the players in the list is active in that category.

E.g. if you [search](http://www.sc2ranks.com/search/exact/am/hello) for a character with the exact name "hello" in the server "Americas", you'll see 5 characters. only three of them have the name "hello" the other two have the name "Hello" (capital "H"). If you are playing a 1v1 match, only [one](http://www.sc2ranks.com/us/2084157/hello) of them (currently) is active in 1v1's, so that character will most likely be your opponent.

You can also do a rough inference by **looking at their league**, your league, and who is favored according to the loading screen.

E.g. if you are in gold league, and an opponent is favored to beat you, and there are two characters whose names show up in a list after you search, one is in diamond league, and the other in bronze league, then it is likely that your opponent is the one in diamond league.

The SC2Ranks profiles gives the various leagues, and most played race of a character, and plenty of other information.

Also note that you can also access the battle.net profile of a given character by clicking on their character name within the SC2Ranks profile page. This pages gives most of the information available to you that would be available in game.

E.g. the EU server has a player sandwich. If you click on his name in his [SC2Ranks profile](http://www.sc2ranks.com/eu/2375043/Sandwich) you will see his [Starcraft 2 Battle.net profile](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/2375043/1/Sandwich/).

Comment: I'm not certain if searching for this information would be against the EULA, or ethically questionable.

I suspect it should be acceptable, since once you play somebody you have access to their character information through the game client anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible by default, but there are tools that show such informations. However, they work by reading the process memory, which means Warden might recognize them as hacks and your account *might* get banned. I don't know of anyone who got banned for using those tools but, well, that might change. Use at your own risk.

Tools i know of:

http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=328318

http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=294436